# Hive query getting stuck in reducer step

Tags: hadoop, hive

My query getting stuck at 99% in reducer step ,I am using hive 1.2.

The DB.acct_dim is a persistent table with partition on etl_load_month,and the stage table stg.acct_dim_incre is a daily truncate table with delta rows.

The target holds billion of rows and stage can have million rows daily.

Is there any way I can optimize the below to run faster?

If I am specifying the exact partition to read from target then it is working fine ,but there can be multiple partition in stage that I want to pull from target.

```
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set mapred.compress.map.output=true;
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;

SELECT
A.col
,A.col2
,A.col3
FROM DB.acct_dim A ---BIG table (billion rows)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
stg.acct_dim_incre B --SMALL table (with million rows)
ON (A.etl_load_month = B.etl_load_month
      AND A.acct_key = B.acct_key)
WHERE A.etl_load_month IN ( --partition column
        SELECT etl_load_month
        FROM stg.acct_dim_incre
        )
AND B.acct_key IS NULL
;
```

Comment: how many mappers and reducers are being spawned when you run your query?

Comment: @TheRandomSuit - 5000 mappers & 320 reducers,and getting stuck at 319. also it is not eliminating partition which I am filtering in WHERE condition ,is there any alternative?

Comment: I would try to decrease the amount of mappers being created with the setting mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize If this setting is larger than the default block size it will decrease the amount of mappers being created. Typical adjusting it between 2-8 times the default block size is the ideal range.